# Django ajax response contains cloudflare script

Tags: ajax, django, python-2.7, cloudflare

I am learning Django by developing a web application. I have added the site to [cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/overview) CDN's free service. After a long learning curve i am able to send request to Django application using ajax, but strangely the response contains the script from cloudflare embedded as part of it.

Example ajax response:

```
<html><body>No arguments passed<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
try{if (!window.CloudFlare) {var CloudFlare=[{verbose:0,p:0,byc:0,owlid:"cf",bag2:1,mirage2:0,oracle:0,paths:{cloudflare:"/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=1613a3a185/"},atok:"b4c8a1a8481c9535dc367c9b4c8c52ab",petok:"e3070e55a3a1fceb44356d479cfa086f3dd56bbe-1429555139-1800",zone:"mydjango.in",rocket:"0",apps:{}}];CloudFlare.push({"apps":{"ape":"0c86dff90b5e1a63e6c69c775ca3d309"}});!function(a,b){a=document.createElement("script"),b=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0],a.async=!0,a.src="//ajax.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/nexp/dok3v=7e13c32551/cloudflare.min.js",b.parentNode.insertBefore(a,b)}()}}catch(e){};
//]]>
</script>
</body></html>
```

The `views.py` code to return the response:

```
def send_response(request):
    inpval = request.GET.get('inputval','')
    if not inpval:
        html = "<html><body>No arguments passed</body></html>"
    else:
        html = "<html><body> %s </body></html>" % inpval
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

Can anyone help me understand how to remove this extra script from cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

Well, i figured out the issue, cloudflare is adding its own `<script>` tag just before `</body>`. So, instead of returning the result with html tags, just retrieved the values and processed them in the client.

Example:

```
if not inpval:
        html = "No arguments passed"
```